# Identify this Android game?

Tags: android, game-identification

[image: Looks as if it is an endless arcade game for android]

I need help identifying this endless Android game.

Any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 5):

This game is called [ALONE](http://www.alone-game.com/).

It costs $2 and is available for Android 2.3+ and IOS 5.0+

This is a fast paced, procedural (endless), sci-fi runner game created by [Laser Dog](http://www.laserdog.co.uk/). The game is praised for its artistic elements and the gameplay is focused on speed and quick reactive actions.

The aim of this game is to journey through space. Dodge obstacles such as rocks and comets to achieve the highest score you can.